# Oracle Case in Where Clause Error

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause

I'm working on a query that will eventually become paramaterized, but I'm getting confused about how to make my `WHERE` clause work.

As a simple example, suppose I have a table with a date column and I either want to get data for a date range if the boolean value is set **OR** just get the data for the last date in the table if the boolean = false... I figured somethign like this would work:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    MyTable
WHERE
    CASE WHEN ('TRUE' = 'TRUE') THEN
        MyDate BETWEEN To_Date('2014-08-04', 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND To_Date('2014-08-05', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
    ELSE
        MyDate = (SELECT MAX(MyDate) FROM MyTable)
    END
```

Obviously, once I get this working, I'll put in the parameters for the boolean and the 2 dates.

But I'm getting an error for the `THEN ...` part of the Case clause - The `BETWEEN` keyword is highlighted and the error is `[1]: ORA-00905: missing keyword`

If I try and run it with either statement separately (`MyDate BETWEEN ...` or `MyDate = ...`), it works just fine, it's only when I put it in the `CASE` statement that the error occurs... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `myDate =` should be pulled outside the `case`. However, since you use both `between` and `=` I would recommend this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE ('true' = 'true' and MyDate BETWEEN To_Date('2014-08-04', 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND To_Date('2014-08-05', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
OR    ('true' != 'true' and MyDate = (SELECT MAX(MyDate) FROM MyTable))
```